# HTML Range Slider w/ JS to Display Value

Tags: javascript, html

The JS being used to display the value of an HTML range slider is working fine for the first item (A1). However, I want to use it for item A2 too (and there are actually 20 items, so it needs to be used over and over 19 more times). Is there a way to write the code for multiple iterations?

```js
 const slideValue = document.querySelector("span");
      const inputSlider = document.querySelector("input");
      inputSlider.oninput = (()=>{
        let value = inputSlider.value;
        slideValue.textContent = value;
        slideValue.style.left = (value/.1) + "%";
        slideValue.classList.add("show");
      });
      inputSlider.onblur = (()=>{
        slideValue.classList.remove("show");
      });
```

```html
<body>
<div class="itemstatement">A1. Blah Blah Blah.</div>
<div class="range">
<div class="sliderValue"><span>0</span></div>
<div class="field">
<div class="value left">0</div>
<input type="range" id="A1" name="A1" min="0" max="10" value="0" steps="1">
<div class="value right">10</div>
</div></div>

<div class="itemstatement">A2. Blah Blah Blah.</div>
<div class="range">
<div class="sliderValue"><span>0</span></div>
<div class="field">
<div class="value left">0</div>
<input type="range" id="A2" name="A2" min="0" max="10" value="0" steps="1">
<div class="value right">10</div>
</div></div></div></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely there is. You will easily recognize your own code, wrapped inside a for loop.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".range");
elems.forEach(function(elem) {
  const slideValue = elem.querySelector("span");
  const inputSlider = elem.querySelector("input");
  inputSlider.oninput = (() => {
    let value = inputSlider.value;
    slideValue.textContent = value;
    slideValue.style.left = (value / .1) + "%";
    slideValue.classList.add("show");
  });
  inputSlider.onblur = (() => {
    slideValue.classList.remove("show");
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="itemstatement">A1. Blah Blah Blah.</div>
<div class="range">
  <div class="sliderValue"><span>0</span></div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="value left">0</div>
    <input type="range" id="A1" name="A1" min="0" max="10" value="0" steps="1">
    <div class="value right">10</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="itemstatement">A2. Blah Blah Blah.</div>
<div class="range">
  <div class="sliderValue"><span>0</span></div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="value left">0</div>
    <input type="range" id="A2" name="A2" min="0" max="10" value="0" steps="1">
    <div class="value right">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```